# In Lotus Notes, How do you determine what database file an embedded view came from

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am modifying an existing notes database.  One form contains an embedded view which appears to be from a different notes database as the views that are selectable are not in the current database.  I have some ideas where the source of the embedded view is, but I would like to have a better way to tell other than just guessing as we have a large number of databases.

Secondary to that can you change the database an embedded view is coming from without deleting and recreating the element?  For example if I want to shift the source of an embedded view from a development database to the production version of the same database, how would I do that?

Just to be clear,  this is an old question about Notes v7.0.

Comment: Why the downvote, and on a 3 year old question for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unforetunately there is no frontend to find this out. And no frontend to change this. 
The only possibility is to Right- Click the Form in the left navigationpane and Click on "Edit with DXL". Then you get the "source" code of the form, and there you will find the embedded view:

```
<embeddedview name='YourViewAlias' database='C1257299904BB19C' 
 showactionbar='true'widthtype='fitwindow' height='5.9056in' scrollbars='true'>
  <code event='showsinglecategory'>
    <formula>SingleCategoryFormula</formula>
  </code>
</embeddedview>
```

in "database" you find the ReplicaID of the database where the view comes from.

Take care: DXL- Edit is not 100% round trip... some formattings may be lost, if you save the form in that editor (though I did not yet find something missing)

Comment: Good idea.  Unfortunately I am stuck at domino 7.0, and Edit with DXL isn't one of the options.

Comment: Then you need to export as xml (with an agent), modify the xml in the exported file and then reimport the xml (using another agent)... Example code can be found in the dxlexporter class in the Designer help

Comment: There is menu option in designer to export selected element to DXL. I am sorry, I have no R7 client installed to point you exactly, but I am sure it is there since R6.

Comment: You are eight, the menu is there... Unfortunately the import button is missing, so for that you have to code LotusScript..

Answer (score 0):

The same info that @Torsten referenced has got to be there if you look for it in [NotesPeek](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24005686). It will just be a lot harder to find.

If you make a copy of the form, though, and delete everything except that embedded view, then look at the copy of the form using NotesPeek, you should be able to zero in on it pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Open the document in the Notes Client, bring up File->Properties and click/focus on the embedded view.
Then select Database on the properties info box and the details about the database the embedded view is from will show.

Comment: tested in 6.5.4 and 9.0.1, can't see why it wouldn't work in v7.0